# What is different of IF BRANCH and AND as OPERATOR?

Tags: syntax, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

Sometimes i used to use if branch, sometimes AND operand.
But i feel they are both same.
What their different actually?
Any there example case which i must use that ONE only?

For example:

```
//Defining variable
a=2
b=3
```

```
if(a==2){
 if(b==3){
 println("OK");
 }
}
```

It's equal with

```
if (a==2 && b==3){
 println("OK");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the first doubly-nested `if` condition when the inner `if` had an `else` branch, e.g.

```
if (a == 2) {
    if (b == 3) {
        println("OK");
    }
    else {
        println("not OK")
    }
}
```

If you *don't* have this requirement, then the second more concise version is probably what most would choose to use:

```
if (a == 2 && b == 3) {
    println("OK");
}
```